# Thread 1: signal SIGBART button error

Tags: swift, xcode

```js
2016-12-29 11:03:12.874 Albhabet City 1[9872:259138] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Albhabet_City_1.IntroViewController 0x7fcf8ec14d60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key play.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c69d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010336221e objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c69c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
 3   Foundation                          0x0000000102e709df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
 4   UIKit                               0x0000000104228293 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
 5   UIKit                               0x000000010449c79e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
 6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c0e9e0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
 7   UIKit                               0x000000010449b122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
 8   UIKit                               0x000000010422e9c5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
 9   UIKit                               0x000000010422f2e7 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
 10  UIKit                               0x000000010422f61c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
 11  UIKit                               0x000000010422fe70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
 12  UIKit                               0x0000000104af06a4 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
 13  UIKit                               0x000000010420a702 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141
 14  UIKit                               0x0000000104242e97 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956
 15  UIKit                               0x000000010424626b -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
 16  UIKit                               0x0000000104245d51 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
 17  UIKit                               0x000000010424b41e -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
 18  UIKit                               0x0000000104708fcc __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
 19  UIKit                               0x00000001048631dd -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 447
 20  UIKit                               0x0000000104862fed -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
 21  UIKit                               0x00000001048632af -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
 22  UIKit                               0x000000010408f8bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
 23  UIKit                               0x0000000104215c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
 24  UIKit                               0x0000000104215f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
 25  UIKit                               0x0000000104214e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
 26  UIKit                               0x00000001040fd545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
 27  UIKit                               0x00000001040fec33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
 28  UIKit                               0x00000001040ab9ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
 29  UIKit                               0x000000010489872d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
 30  UIKit                               0x0000000104891463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
 31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103c0e761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
 32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bf398c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
 33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bf2e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
 34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bf2884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
 35  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109cc2a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
 36  UIKit                               0x000000010408dc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
 37  Albhabet City 1                     0x0000000102d7adbf main + 111
 38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010734868d start + 1
 39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

The page above is the error that I received

```js
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class IntroViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any)
    {
    player.play()
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        
        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
            
            
        }
        catch
        {
            //error
        }

    
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

This is the page that fails to reveal itself when I click on the button to it on the phone simulator.

I'm making an app that has multiple scenes. whenever I click my first button to another slide on my simulator, it switches me to "AppDelegate.swift" and on the "class app delegate..." it gives me error"thread 1: signal SIGBART.[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hr7h.png),
[the failed simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx7y4.png),

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: And look at / post the stacktrace

Comment: Another interesting part would be the contents of the view at the bottom right where it has printed an actual cause of the error and a stack trace.  Try copying that and pasting it into your question.

Comment: The crucial information is in the first line: *this class* - (IntroViewController) - *is not key value coding-compliant for the key **play***

Comment: Did you know that Stack Overflow is searchable?

Comment: I'll guess that when you were connecting your UI to this view controller, you chose to add an IBOutlet called "play" when you really wanted an IBAction.  You then probably deleted the outlet in code without disconnecting it in the UI visual editor.

Comment: Whenever I try to set the intro view controller class to "IntroViewController", my computer makes a ding and doesn't save the name "IntroViewController". All of my other View Controllers do this with no problem. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIGABRT errors usually happen if you broke a connection between IB and your code. Like for example, maybe if you made an action connection from your button to a `@IBAction` and deleted it, then it will cause an SIGABRT. You can fix it if you delete your button then make a new connection and rewrite the code.

Here is a link that you can view:
[SIGABRT Explained! (General Solution) - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StNo1ZBmxww)